# Updating a single item in React context state

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, state, react-context

So I have a Context of the following format:

```
class UserProvider extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.initialize = (details) => {
            this.setState(state => {
                //Setting each item individually here
                //e.g state.a = details.a
            })
        }

        this.editA = () => {
            this.setState(state => {
                //change A here
            })
        }

        this.editB = () => {
            this.setState(state => {
                //Change B here
            })
        }

        this.state = {
            a: null,
            b: null,
            editA: this.editA,
            editB: this.editB
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <User.Provider value={this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </User.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

So for each state, I have a separate function to update it. If I want to update only a single state, what should I do?

Comment: the just update that field and do nothing for others.. this.setState({a:'"value"})

Comment: @EugenSunic Wouldn't that still require separate functions for each field when I want to access it through a consumer

Comment: you mean you want only one fucnction to update a field instead of having n functions for n fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider implementing a generic function so that you can control your key and the corresponding value.

i.e.

```
const changeField = (key, value) => this.setState({ [key]: value});
```

Function call

```
changeField('a','value_a')
changeField('b','value_b')
```